# Обучение разработке под Android

Tags: android, .net

Сам еще довольно молодой, с логическим мышлением в программировании у меня далеко неплохо, проблема всегда была одна, незнание компонентов, инструментов той или иной платформы разработки. В данном случае нужно набрать хороших знаний для разработки под Android (нужно для работы) за 2, 3 месяца, но и не помешало бы для других платформ (.Net). Еще большую проблему в развитии играет незнание английского языка. Кто что может посоветовать, как набраться хорошой практики?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственный совет: учите английский и [тут](http://developer.android.com/)
есть, конечно, аналоги на русском, но их мало и явно недостаточно для изучения инструментария.

Comment: Да это понятно займусь этим,но меня интересует методы обучения,как опытные программисты обучались инструментариям,читать или больше практиковаться?Как набирали знаний.

Comment: Назвать себя опытным программистом не позволяет совесть, но лино я почувствовал прогресс, когда устроился на работу. В моем случае курить мануалы - не то: прочитанное почти сразу испаряется. Технический английски, кстати, несложен - учится довольно просто по ходу чтения мануалов.

Comment: 2 Iranda, вы мой ответ интерпретировали неверно. На этом сайте нет русского текста.

Comment: По-моему, мануалы это очень хорошо, но не стоит забывать о технических деталях. Т.е. нашли мануал, полезли в доки, посмотрели какие методы отрабатывают, как они работают. В процессе отладки можно их код посмотреть.
Что касается запоминания - после нескольких итераций рефакторинга запоминается многое :)

Answer (score 2):

Читайте книги, доступные на русском, учите английский, читая доку, читайте книги на английском, гуглите на английском(гуглите вопрос на англ и находите ответ на stackoverflow). Техническая терминология усваивается неплохо и из наших книг. Ну а потом вы просто будете расширять накопленную базу.

И начните с языка. В данном случае с Java.

Comment: Я Java C++ # хорошо знаю,опыт был хороший,всегда просто проблемы были с инструментариями платформы(Qt,.Net) а сейчас с Androidom.Буду заниматься спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Вот это тебе для начала: [this.](http://www.rgagnon.com/howto.html)