# Обучение программированию под android и windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, java, android

Имею навык и опыт программирования по паскалю и делфи, закончил 1 курс института и понял, что ко всему придется идти самому. Заинтересовался мобильной разработкой (игры, полезные программы). Интересующие платформы - Android (так как у самого планшет из этого семейства) и Windows Phone 7-8 так как от недавних пор телефон производства Nokia. Если WP более-менее все понятно, у них есть сайт-самоучитель да и причем на нашем великом могучем (с английским у меня пока тяжело) + книги. То нормальных мануалов по андроиду нету, по-крайней мере я таких не нашёл. Есть пару вопросов например, что изучать для того чтобы взяться за SDK оных - C# либо Java? + вопрос: какие языки еще нужно изучить для того чтобы иметь базу работы с этими ОС?
Буду благодарен любым советам (книги-самоучители, тематические форумы, видеоуроки) от старших наставников по поводу обоих платформ, и еще если не в тягость посоветуйте сразу книги и по языкам.

Comment: [гуглить][1] по форуму не пробовали? 

[1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/135019/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-android

Comment: [этого мало?][1]


  [1]: http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3693656

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/125783/262779

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692639/262779

Answer (score 5):

Мне кажется, что, если не самый лучший, то точно один из лучших ресурсов, на котором учат программировать под android - startandroid.ru.   
Уроки очень понятные и простые.

Answer (score 4):

Вы действительно считаете, что прочитав 15 книг, которые вам может быть посоветуют, вы сможете писать приложения? **имхо**, раз у вас есть некоторый **начальный уровень**, читать такие книги не только необязательно, но и не нужно.

мое мнение: начинаем с "how to create your first app for android/winphone/ios" из гугла, а продолжаем - учась ***программировать***.

Придумали что-то типа "хочу написать вот такую штуку для вот этой оси", садитесь и начинайте писать. Вопросы, возникающие в процессе, решаются с помощью хэшкода/гугла/stackoverflow. Что-то заработало - посмотрите на написанный вами код, **ужаснитесь** и перепишите, основываясь на новых знаниях, приобретенных в процессе. Причем слово "ужаснитесь" - действительно ключевое. Дописали свое первое приложение (допустим, простейший парсер какого-нибудь новостного сайта), усложните себе задачу. И так далее, не забывая улучшать написанное ранее.

Таким образом, через несколько таких приложений у вас будет неплохое представление о возможностях платформы, подводных камнях и особенностях реализации. А это и есть цель самообучения.

Comment: @Макс Жуков, не у одного вас здесь замечаю такие советы - дескать, нечего читать эти книжки, ничему хорошему из них вы не научитесь. Откуда такая нелюбовь к литературе? Это как в старом анекдоте получается - "чукча не читатель, чукча писатель"

Comment: @DreamChild, ни о какой нелюбви к литературе речи не идет. просто я искренне считаю, что человеку, который хочет научиться писать под какую-то платформу, на начальном этапе значительно полезнее практика. А вот уже после того, как все, что называется, "пощупал", можно и нужно углублять знания.

Comment: @Макс Жуков это довольно вредно - практика без теории и теория без практики. В случае практики без теории обычно получаются ремесленники. И это в лучшем случае. А переучиваться из самоучек в профессионалы, как показывает практика, куда сложнее, и  болезненнее, чем становиться профессионалом изначально

Comment: @DreamChild, люди на 1 курсе в большинстве своем хотят стать ремесленниками. Чтобы хоть что-то уметь, и на основании этих умений определяться, чем заниматься в дальнейшем.

Comment: У меня сложилось впечатление будто студент второго курса - уже пропащая душа какая-то) Мне действительно хотелось бы научиться чему-нибудь стоящему но я впервые слышу о таких классах как "ремесленники/профессионалы" и обусловленными/не обусловленными переходами между ними. Конечно, я думаю как и остальные, мне хочеться стать профессионалом и потому хотелось литературу, уроков, наставника с возможностью совмещать и то и другое разом. Наверное потому и задал вопрос наново, так как толковых ответов на форумах я не находил.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы мог посоветовать вам источник вот: http://computersbooks.net/ всего хорошего:)