# Книги и учебные ресурсы по Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, книги

Давайте соберем подборку хорошей литературы и ресурсов (для разработчиков с разным уровнем владения материалом) по ***ОС Android*** (архитектура, безопасность, разработка *UI/UX*, трюки, многопоточность и тд.), разработке приложений под нее и популярным библиотекам. 
Предлагаю добиписывать материалы в общий ответ, как это сделано в аналогичных вопросах.

**ВАЖНО**: так как разрабатывать приложения ***ОС Android*** можно на разных языках (C, C++, Java, JavaScript, Kotlin, Go и т.д.), в ответе на данный вопрос не стоит указывать книги по этим языкам программирования, за исключением книг, которые непосредственно описывают использование какого либо языка программирования в контексте ***ОС Android***. Если у книгиг есть перевод на русккий язык (или несколько от разных издательств), указывайте, пожалуйста, книги и авторов с наиболее корректным переводом.

**P/S** прошу не закрывать данный вопрос модераторов, заблокировать вопрос с целью иметь все ресурсы в одном ответе и по возможности внести в поддерживаемый сообществом [Сборник учебных ресурсов по программированию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: Вот, привлекли внимание, сделал общим. ))

Comment: Я поискал разные другие вопросы с поиском книг по Android. Все найденные отметил дубликатами к этому. Теперь с них ссылки ведут сюда. Это способ привлечения внимания. Эти вопросы видны в панели «Связанные» справа, всего 11 штук + 1 общий список.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### **Для начинающих**

- *Head First. Android Development: A Brain-Friendly Guide.* Dawn Griffiths. O'Reilly Media, 2015, ISBN: 978-1-4493-6218-8

  Русский перевод: *Head First. Программирование для Android.* Гриффитс Д. Питер, 2016, ISBN: 978-5-496-02171-5
- *Android NDK: Beginners's Guide (2nd Edition).* Sylvain Ratabouil. Packt Publishing Ltd., 2015, ISBN: 978-1-7839-8964-5

  Русский перевод: *Android NDK. Руководство для начинающих.* Сильвен Ретабоуил.    ДМК Пресс, 2016, ISBN: 978-5-97060-394-9

### **Средний уровень**

- *Mastering Android NDK.*  Sergey Kosarevsky, Viktor Latypov. Packt Publishing Ltd., 2015, ISBN: 978-1-7852-8833-3
- Книги от [CommonsWare](https://commonsware.com). Эти книги не издаются в печатном формате - только цифровой (PDF, EPUB3 и MOBI/Kindle). Распространяются по подписке на официальном сайте. Каждая книга является именной для подписчика. Часто выходят переиздания. У книг очень большое сообщество.

  - *The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development.*
  - *Android's Architecture Components.*
  - *GraphQL and Android.*

### **Профессиональный уровень**

- *Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide (3rd Edition) (Big Nerd Ranch Guides)*. Bill Phillips, Chris Stewart, Kristin Marsicano.  ISBN: 978-0-1347-0605-4

  Русский перевод: *Android. Программирование для профессионалов.* Билл Филлипс, К. Стюарт, Кристин Марсикано. Питер, 2017, ISBN: 978-5-4461-0413-0

---

### **Литература по асинхронному программированию и многопоточности**

- *Efficient Android Threading*. Anders Göransson.  O’Reilly Media, Inc. ISBN: 978-1-449-36413-7

  Русский перевод: *Эффективное использование потоков в операционной системе Android. Технологии асинхронной обработки данных.* Андерс Ёранссон. ДМК Пресс, 2015, ISBN: 978-5-97060-168-6
- *Asynchronous Android Programming (2nd Edition).* Helder Vasconcelos,  Packt Publishing Ltd., 2016, ISBN: 978-1-7858-8324-8
- *Android Concurrency (Android Deep Dive, 1st Edition)*. G. Blake Meike.  Addison-Wesley Professional, 2016, ISBN: 978-0-1341-7743-4

---

### **Безопасность в ОС Android**

- *Android Security Internals: An In-Depth Guide to Android's Security Architecture.* Nikolay Elenkov. No Starch Press, 2014, ISBN: 978-1-5932-7581-5
- *Android Security Cookbook.* Keith Makan, Scott Alexander-Bown, Packt Publishing Ltd., 2013, ISBN: 978-1-7821-6716-7
- *Android Hacker's Handbook.* Joshua J. Drake, Zach Lanier, Collin Mulliner, Pau Oliva Fora, Stephen A. Ridley, Georg Wicherski. Wiley, 2014, ISBN: 978-1-1186-0864-7
- *Bulletproof Android: Practical Advice for Building Secure Apps (Developer's Library).* Godfrey Nolan. Addison-Wesley Professional, 2014, ISBN: 978-0-1339-9332-5

---

### **UI/UX в OC Android**

- *Android User Interface Design: Implementing Material Design for Developers (2nd Edition) (Usability)*. Ian G. Clifton. Addison-Wesley Professional, 2015. ISBN: 978-0-1341-9140-9

  Русский перевод: *Проектирование пользовательского интерфейса в Android.*     Ян Клифтон. ДМК Пресс, 2017, ISBN: 978-5-97060-449-6

---

### **Литература по принципам, шаблонам и методикам разработки**

- *Android Design Patterns and Best Practice (1st Edition).* Kyle Mew. Packt Publishing Ltd., 2016, ISBN-13: 978-1-7864-6721-8

---

### **Android для встраиваемых систем (embedded systems)**

- *Embedded Programming with Android: Bringing Up an Android System from Scratch (Android Deep Dive, 1st Edition).* Roger Ye, Addison-Wesley Professional, 2015, ISBN-13: 978-0-1340-3000-5

---

### **Тестирование приложений в ОС Android**

- *Android Application Testing Guide* Diego Torres Milano,
  Packt Publishing Ltd., 2011, ISBN-13: 978-1-8495-1350-0

---

### **Системное програмиирование в ОС Android**

- *Inside the Android OS: Building, Customizing, Managing and Operating Android System Services (Android Deep Dive, 1st Edition)*. G. Blake Meike, Addison-Wesley Professional, 2018, ISBN-13: 978-0-1340-9634-6
- *Android System Programming.* Roger Ye, Packt Publishing Ltd., 2017, ISBN-13: 978-1-7871-2536-0

---

### **Реактивное программирование**

- *Reactive Programming with RxJava. Creating Asynchronous, Event-Based Applications*. Ben Christensen, Tomasz Nurkiewicz. -O'Reilly Media, 2016, ISBN-13: 978-1491931653

  Русский перевод: Томаш Нуркевич, Бен Кристенсен. *Реактивное программирование с применением RxJava. Разработка асинхронных событийно-ориентированных приложений* / пер. с англ. Слинкин А.А. - М.: ДМК Пресс, 2017, ISBN: 978-5-97060-496-0

---

### **Онлайн-ресурсы**

- [Сайт Александра Климова](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/)
- [startandroid.ru](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html)
- [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)
- [material.io](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/introduction.html)
- [Android Developer Fundamentals (Version 2)](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/index.html)

---

### **Официальные бесплатные курсы от Google**

- [Android Basics (RUS)](https://javarush.ru/quests/QUEST_GOOGLE_ANDROID)
- [Developing Android Apps - Intermediate level (ENG)](https://www.udacity.com/course/new-android-fundamentals--ud851)
- [Android app development - Advanced level (ENG)](https://www.udacity.com/course/advanced-android-app-development--ud855)
- [Kotlin Bootcamp for Programmers (ENG)](https://www.udacity.com/course/kotlin-bootcamp-for-programmers--ud9011)
- [Developing Android Apps with Kotlin (ENG)](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps-with-kotlin--ud9012)
- [Kotlin for Android Developers (ENG)](https://www.udacity.com/course/kotlin-for-android-developers--ud888)
- [Advanced Android with Kotlin (ENG)](https://www.udacity.com/course/advanced-android-with-kotlin--ud940)
- [Android Performance (ENG)](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-performance--ud825)
- [Material Design for Android Developers (ENG)](https://www.udacity.com/course/material-design-for-android-developers--ud862)
- [Firebase in a Weekend: Android (ENG)](https://www.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-android--ud0352)
- [Build Native Mobile Apps with Flutter (ENG)](https://www.udacity.com/course/build-native-mobile-apps-with-flutter--ud905)

Comment: `Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide` не относится к профессиональному уровню.

Comment: @post_zeew а к какому? (можете поправить ответ) ну или я сам поправлю, аргументируйте свою точку зрения ...

Comment: Я бы отнес ее к начальному или среднему уровню – эта книга начинается с создания hello world.

Comment: Согласен с @post_zeew Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide -  книга для начинающих. Взял её в руки ничего не зная об андроиде и прошел от hello world до вполне серьезного приложения. В ней очень хорошо объясняются самые основы, но без каких либо глубоких погружений в тему

Comment: https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/index.html самая лучшая книга котороя часто обновляется