# Комбинирование ScrollView и BottomNavigationBar в Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, android-scrollview

При комбинировании `ScrollView` и `BottomNavigationBar` возникает сперва незаметная, но очень нехорошая ошибка. Если мы открываем клавиатуру и нам нужно что-то ввести в `EditText` в том же фрагменте, то мы получаем интересную картину: `BottomNavigationBar` оказывается выше клавиатуры. Как это решается? `BottomNavigationBar` находится в разметке `Activity`, а `ScrollView` - во фрагменте.

[image: Вот так]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в разметке `Activity` атрибут `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` в `AndroidManifest.xml` файле.

Comment: Спасибо :) А где можно подробнее прочитать о подобных атрибутах? Документация от Google?

Comment: @АлександрЧуркин конечно есть все в доках. но можно и на русском почитать [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/keyboard.php). Очень рекомендую вам. А так же ознакомьтесь с [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-android)