# Какие самые свежие книги по андроид разработке посоветуете? ан

Tags: android, книги

Знаю, что по книгам андроид изучать не айс, но все таки где то пишут, что это нужно. Книга(и) обязательно на русском.

Comment: раз вам не айс книги читать - не читайте.

Comment: Нет, я в другом смысле. Именно книги по АНДРОИД читать не рекомендуется, так как технологии быстро меняются в этой области

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-android

Автор, учитесь пользоваться поиском. Хотя это тоже не айс, да?

Comment: по андроиду есть множество прекрасных книг, которые постоянно обновляются с выходом обновлений sdk. просто переводят их на русский спустя 5 лет. (если вообще переводят)

Comment: head first android

Comment: все еще актуален android 5, который вышел в 2014 году и технологии технологиями, а лучшей базы, чем книга, вам никакие видеоуроки или статейки в интернете не дадут (только хороший преподаватель предпочтительней),а без базы никакие новейшие технологии не сделают из вас толкового работчика. Почитайте книгу того же предложенного в ответе Филлипса и удивитесь, как мало вы знали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [RU] Android. Программирование для профессионалов - Билл Филлипс, К. Стюарт, Кристин Марсикано
2. [ENG]
   Mark L. Murphy - The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development 8.8

Comment: 3-е издание 2017 г.

Comment: Добавьте в общественный список, пожалуйста (с соблюдением формата): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/692640/181100

Comment: @D-side она там уже есть, в разделе для профессионалов почему то ..

Comment: В таком случае, исправляюсь: сначала проверяйте такие общественные списки на предмет наличия там предлагаемых книг и добавляйте их, если их там нет :)