# Что нужно для написания приложения на Android?

Tags: android

Меня интересует инструментарий для создания приложения на Android.
С чем придется столкнуться, какой язык нужно учить?
Т.е., нужно разработать приложения на Android. Что для этого нужно?

Comment: андроид студио и язык java или kotlin

Comment: Можно через платформу Unity, язык можно C#, но для Android лучше Java.

Comment: я бы добавил, что знание самого API Android нужно обязательно. Найдите книгу Б.Филлипс "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" 3-издание 2017, там с первых шагов все объясняется. Если вы не знакомы с языком программирования Java (или Kotlin) то его надо изучить отдельно **перед** тем, как писать программу на Android. Всякие кроссплатформенные решения на C#, JS и прочей экзотике я бы оставил до появления понимания, что вообще происходит.

Comment: Нужна оф.документация по андроид https://developer.android.com/index.html , знание Java SE https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/ и XML. Литература: Книга «Java 8. Полное руководство» Герберт Шилдт, Книга Head First. Программирование для Android(Anthony J.F. Griffiths, Дэвид Гриффитс), Head First Изучаем Java (Кати Сьерра, Берт Бейтс), Android. Программирование для профессионалов( Б.Филлипс), Android для разработчиков 3-е издание(Пол Дейтел, Харви Дейтел).

Comment: @ИванТ скорее Java core. Зачем в android апплеты, бины, awt и swing?

Comment: @pavlofff, их нужно пропустить, забыл указать этот момент.

Comment: Также ознакомьтесь с [тем что уже есть на ресурсе касательно учебных материалов по Android.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Установить на компьютер **Андроид студио** - это среда разработки.
Зная свой проект (задачу), можно приступать шаг за шагом делать UI (верстать видимую часть приложения).
В этом помогут уроки по **юдасити** (на анг, есть ру субтитры).

Второй момент - изучение **Java**. Знание Java поможет быстро освоить Kotlin - более модернизированный язык.

Третий момент - отдельные аспекты в программировании (RxJava - многопоточность; чистая архитектура и др).

По опыту, сталкиваясь с задачей, я обретаю нужный мне запас инструментов, который постепенно расширяю. Сразу все читать/изучать - слишком запутанно будет. Держать баланс: теория - практика.

**Вывод:** рекомендую уроки https://www.udacity.com/

затем переходить на уроки Java https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/

Все это практиковать по отношению к своему проекту.

Answer (score 1):

Java, библиотеки android для начала
Потом Sql, начала xml(можно без них)
попробуй оф. руководство на сайте android studio
или пошагово startandroid