# Как пользоваться библиотекой Smart Location Library для Android?

Tags: android, геолокация

Здравствуйте!

Как начинающий андроид-разработчик, пытаюсь использовать библиотеку Smart Location Library для определения координат.

Нашел библиотеку [Smart Location Library](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=1321), но как ее использовать, пока не разберусь.

В соответствии с документацией, в build.gragle подключил зависимость, выполнил sync.

Теперь в onCreate вставляю код:

```
SmartLocation.with(context).location()
.start(new OnLocationUpdatedListener() {
```

});

Однако context подсвечивается красным. Что туда подставить?
Пока отсутствует понимание, как у начинающего.

Comment: если этот код в активити - то вместо `context` напишите `this`, если в фрагменте - `getActivity()`. Вообще я бы вам не рекомендовал браться за какие то библиотеки Smart Location Library когда вы полный ноль в базовых вещах, вам же наверное не приходит в голову "удачная" идея: я начинающий хирург и делаю операцию на сердце, но пока отсутствует понимание, что такое скальпель ... Книжки для начала [почитайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/692640/177345)

Comment: Спасибо большое.