# Какие существуют популярные API для подключения к Android?

Tags: android

Я понимаю, что такое API в принципе, хотя, может и неправильно понимаю. Допустим, есть какой-то твиттер канал и я с него твиты вставляю себе в приложение. Это будет являться использованием API? Если не я не прав, то приведите более удачный пример.

Моих знаний не хватает, чтобы правильно и грамотно задать вопрос, спрашиваю как могу. Если Вы поняли суть, прошу помочь мне с разъяснениями на этот счёт.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-android)

Comment: @0xdb я думаю нет, так как вопрос в поле конкретный.. А так, если есть книги со всей теорией и офф доки, зачем  stackoverflow?

Comment: @TimurMukhortov "я думаю нет, так как вопрос в поле конкретный" - если вы так думаете, то ответьте на вопрос ТС.

Comment: @KeyJibo что вы понимаете под API?

Comment: Практически все популярные сервисы имеют API. Узнать о них можно из официальных ресурсов этих сервисов. Каждый сервис имеет свой собственный API и одного универсального на всех не существует. Например [vkontakte api](https://vk.com/dev)

Comment: @TimurMukhortov что-то, к чему можно обратиться из android-приложения и что-то запросить, и тебе сервис это предоставит.

Comment: @pavlofff Вы можете в личной беседе проконсультировать меня немного, ваша помощь очень здорово бы мне помогла и я Вам был бы благодарен.

Comment: я не работаю с API каких либо ресурсов. Если у вас есть проблема, задайте по ней вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Определение(из википедии [[ссылка на источник.]](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/API)):**

> API (программный интерфейс приложения, интерфейс прикладного
>   программирования) (англ. application programming interface, API
>   [эй-пи-ай]) — набор готовых классов, процедур, функций, структур и
>   констант, предоставляемых приложением (библиотекой, сервисом) или
>   операционной системой для использования во внешних программных
>   продуктах. Используется программистами при написании всевозможных
>   приложений.

**Объяснение:**

Представьте так, что у вас есть изолированный модуль в программе, который что-то делает, например обрабатывает какие то данные.

Я как разработчик этого модуля хочу чтоб вы могли отправлять данные для этого модуля и получать. Тогда я делаю прослойку (`API`), которая будет предоставлять вам эту возможность.

Все что вам остается это обратиться к этому слою и дернуть нужный вам метод на чтение\запись данных с нужными параметрами.

Также будет происходить с сервисом Твитера, ВК и т.д.. У этих сервисов есть документация по `API`, как нужно работать с этим слоем, к примеру:

- какие параметры нужно отправить
- какого типа
- что вам вернут в ответ

Правда предварительно нужно ***сериализовать*** объект при отправке и ***десериализовать*** при получение.

**Список популярных API**:

- [developer.github.com/v3/](https://developer.github.com/v3/)
- [vk.com/dev/methods](https://vk.com/dev/methods)

*обращение к модератором и сообществу: я не знаю можно ли указывать ссылки на API, пожалуйста, если нет - удалите. Если можно, то добавьте свое.*

Comment: Спасибо, а есть какие-то популярные api, которыми многие пользуются?

Comment: К примеру от Github https://developer.github.com/v3/