# Как стать android - разработчиком

Tags: java, android

Есть ли какой - то общепринятый алгоритм становления на сей путь ? Понимаю что нужен язык java ,но как понять на чем остановиться в нем чтобы продолжить уже непосредственно создавать приложения?Так же вопрос по самому Android , уроков много , устаревших тоже , вот и вопрос где сейчас актуальные уроки есть ?И какие именно учить чтобы на работу могли взять , так как я понимаю все что есть учить не следует , просто потому что тупо некуда применить. Есть идея своего приложения , но как реализовать вообще не понимаю ... Вот и спрашиваю ,мб есть что то общепринятое ?

Comment: Читаете учебник по Java, потом читаете учебник по Android, после пытаетесь найти стажировку.

Comment: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639) ← Как минимум про Android 5 там есть, не думаю что в Android 8 что-то принципиально поменялось

Comment: _"но как понять на чем остановиться в нем"_ - на базовых умениях (работа с классами, циклы, работа со стандартными сущностями (строки, числа и т.д.)), Начинать создавать приложения. Актуальный пример "как создать первое приложение" есть в официальной документации: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/

Comment: "я понимаю все что есть учить не следует , просто потому что тупо некуда применить. Есть идея своего приложения , но как реализовать вообще не понимаю" - учите все, а потом думайте как это применить в своем приложение. Делайте проекты, выливайте их на Github. Пишите статьи. Люди вас будут критиковать. Вы будете делать выводы. Я так думаю.

Answer (score 0):

Первым делом изучаете **Java Core**, все, что Вы изучите рано или поздно пригодится Вам при создании приложений, сможете реализовывать необходимые Вам задачи. Но это только половина дела. Зная **Java Core**, Вы теперь сможете полноценно "общаться" со средой разработки приложений. Предполагаю, Вы будете использовать **Android Studio**. В первую очередь стоит изучить самый базовый функционал, что и откуда берется, как работает. Даже старые уроки Вам вполне подойдут, которых в инете достаточно, т.к кардинально с момента написания этих уроков в студии ничего не поменялось. В процессе изучения узнаете о различных компонентах студии, как к ним обращаться, использовать, как строится разметка приложения и многое другое.

**Итог:** если вы сейчас не владеете основами языка (**Java Core**), настоятельно рекомендую заняться его изучением и на это время забыть про Android. Если Вы будете хорошо владеть языком, Вам не составит никакого труда написать необходимый Вам функционал. Чтобы "прикрутить" этот функционал к приложению - это уже работа со студией, там будут новые заморочки и велосипеды =)

Answer (score 0):

Могу порекомендовать [курс от специалистов google](https://javarush.ru/quests/QUEST_GOOGLE_ANDROID).
Но, как написал Pollux, без Java Core дальше простых приложений далеко не уйдете.
Как вариант, для Android можно изучать Kotlin, последнее время все больше приложений пишется на нем.