# Посоветуйте книги по Андроид-разработке?

Tags: android

Посоветуйте книги по Андроид-разработке?
Хотелось бы что-то поновее.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxhbmRsZXNzb25zfGd4OjNjMjBlNzMwZDUwNmM2YWM для меня оказался самым лучшим + Климов http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/ . Рекомендую начинать с них, а дальше сориентируетесь

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-android)

Answer (score 0):

Представляю вам список литературы составленный участниками русского сообщества stackoverflow - [список.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-android)