# Какие технологии изучать для программирование под Android на java?

Tags: java, android

Я уже несколько месяцев изучаю язык программирования java, знаю синтаксис языка, умею работать с некоторыми библиотеками, но всё равно развитие в java для меня всё ещё тёмный лес, недавно изучил swing, но вскоре узнал, что эта технология сильно устарела. 
Я хочу заниматься программированием под Android, подскажите, пожалуйста, какие технологии(библиотеки и фреймворки) мне изучать и в каком порядке?
Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: вам подскажут книги

Comment: Android SDK и вот этот сайт http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/android2.php

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416634/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-java       и      https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-android , но могу , конечно, все в примерных подробностях расписать в ответе

Comment: Я бы посмотрел в сторону flutter - чтобы сразу писать и под iOS и под android.

Comment: по языку только java core, никакие свинги и прочие awt не понадобятся в андроид-разработке, андроид использует собственный фреймворк

Comment: Премного благодарен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В прошлом году был один бесплатный курс по Android. Он уже закончился но здесь есть ссылки на лекции, чат и там ещё есть домашние задания https://m.habr.com/ru/post/420573/.

Так же советую почитать книги серии Head First.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!