# Android studio Как изменить начальный шаблон у проекта

Tags: android-studio

Всем привет. Так уж получилось , что я создал новый проект, загрузил все необходимые либы, все подключил, все замечательно , даже написал какой код... Но тут потребовалось чтобы в проекте было выдвижное меню. Загуглил. Нужно создавать новый проект с соответствующим шаблоном. либо через какие то костыли вообще. Можно ли как то перебилдить\переделать проект , чтобы и код с подключенными либами  остались и проект сразу включал это выдвижное меню? Не хочется плодить проекты , стирать и снова все подключать.
Понимаю, вопрос нубский, профи все очевидно, но не новичкам)

Comment: В реальном мире шаблоны не используют. Встраивание выдвижного меню происходит довольно просто - добавляется оно в разметку, в коде пишется пара строк и всё. Да, там множество нюансов, но уж точно не следует воспринимать проблему как необходимость что-то с шаблонами делать. Просто надо разобраться как оно работает и встроить в ваш текущий код.

Comment: любой шаблон - это просто заготовка кода, который вы можете написать сами, причем гораздо компактнее и оптимизированный под свои задачи. вообще, за более 5 лет, лично я использую только один стартовый шаблон - empty activity (или как он там, пустой проект, в общем). Так же нельзя не отметить, что все готовые стартовые шаблоны имеют большое количество избыточного кода.

Comment: Какие то костыли - это самому написать код?  никогда не думал, что писать свой код это какая то проблема, которой 
нужно избегать . Как устроенн [шаблон Navigation Drawer Activity](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/navigation_drawer_activity.php). Можете прочитать и сделать сам, так как вам надо и в три раза короче, чем гугловский индус :)

Comment: @pavlofff Ага, повторил и сделал кароче и не фига не работает, пошли ошибки. Понимаете, Я не фига не понимаю, что обязательно нужно для этого меню, а что является дополнительным и можно опустить. А про костыли , Я имел виду, авторов туториалов, где они через какие то левые контейнеры реализовывают своё меню, что мне вообще не подходит.  Да ведь, легче критиковать, нежели дать минимум необходимого кода) То что вы скинули- это скорее обзор этого шаблона, а это не особо помогает разобраться в проблеме.

Comment: Дело в том, что подробнее, чем в инструкции выше, уже невозможно объяснить, там разжеван до мелочей буквально каждый шаг и весь необходимый код присутствует, это далеко не минимум необходимого кода, а полноценный пошаговый гайд с объяснением каждого шага.

Comment: Если вы не понимаете, что вам не нужно, то повторяйте все, как там написано. Если сделали все в точности, но не работает,задайте новый вопрос с конкретной проблемой - что именно сделали, что не работает, какая ошибка в логкате? Ответ на этот вопрос - нельзя в существующий проект добавить новый стартовый шаблон.

Comment: Понимаешь, это инструкция не подходит - там расписывается конкретно этот объект и не показывается как к проекту, который пуст, прикрутить это меню. Создавать отдельно или стартовое активити менять, нужно ли прописывать что то в манивисте или grad bild? ? Что не нужно в самом шаблоне? Там много данных , не отвечающих на мой вопрос(не в обиду автора сайта). Мне не нужна излишня подробность, мне нужен четкий и ясный ответ, чего там, естественно нет.

Comment: А также если пытаться к пустому проекту притащить этот NavigationView, то линковщик радует вот этой ошибкой, даже если в шаблоном проекте не было её и меню присутствует в проекте : AAPT: error: attribute menu (aka com.example.main_rfid_test:menu) not found.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Покажите как это делается в ответе

Comment: @Deadmyself, долго ответ писать. Для этого надо студию запускать, проект создавать, вспоминать как там оно делается и  прочее. Где-то полчаса-час времени надо тратить. К сожалению столько свободного времени у меня нет(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Пожалуйста, тогда просто распишите, что именно нужно для этого(  Мои попытки тчетны

Comment: @Deadmyself, подключите нужную библиотеку (вроде `design` нужен, но я не уверен). Оберните текущую разметку активити в NavigationDrawer компонент. Вторым его ребёнком поставьте NavigationView. В коде найдите NavigationDrawer и установите ему какой-то класс (вроде что-то типа NavigationDrawerToggle). Переопределите пару методов в активити (надо примеры в сети смотреть чтобы понять какие (они за синхронизацию состояния отвечают)). Вроде всё.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Это выдвигающиеся меню будет у всех страниц проекта? Конкретно вы имеете в виду стартовую страницу?Но у меня там уже что то есть , можно ли создать отдельно страницу и навязать меню на неё?

Comment: Ну... Наверное можно... Вопрос в том, что вы называете страницей проекта. Если это активити - то точно можно. Если фрагменты то, думаю, это настолько сложно (или невозможно), что и не стоит пытаться. Ну или программно запрещать вызов левого меню.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Итого у меня получилось какая та облегченная версия шаблона, где сначала вызывается layot с меню выдвижным и include собираеться нужная версия страницы.  Это правильно ? ЧТобы переключаться между страницами Я просто затираю содержимое родителя include и новый вставляю. Вроде работает норм. Так правильно? Есть мелкая мелочь с картинками, но Я счас задам отдельный вопрос

Comment: @Deadmyself, я не очень вас понял, но, кажется, вы выбрали неудачный вариант. По идее экраны реализуются через фрагменты, реже - через активити. Менять разметку вручную для смены экрана стоит только в очень редких случаях и только если вы полностью понимаете зачем и почему вы так делаете)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Что за фрагменты? Это отдельные файлы layot, которые загружаются по команде?

Comment: Грубо говоря да. обычно в активити есть лишь вьюха-контейнер и в неё как раз и добавляются фрагменты. Они во многом похожи на активити, у них есть похожий жищненный цикл и прочее.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб                                                                                                                    ConstraintLayout parent =  findViewById(R.id.working);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.read_page, null);
            parent.removeAllViews();
            parent.addView(layout); Я вот так их добавляю  ) Жаль код в комменты не особо хочет лезть)

Comment: @Deadmyself, ну... Оно так будет, конечно, работать, но такой подход не используется в серьёзной разработке, т.к. нерасширяем он и слишком много кода оказывается не там где надо. Лучше это делать через фрагменты. Правда, если вы с ними дел не имели - придётся помучиться с их освоением.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб - пожалуйста покажите с чего начать, Я хлебушек)

Comment: Ну... Попробуйте первые два сайта из конца ответа тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE-android