# Как стать middle разработчиком android почти с нуля?

Tags: android

Как стать middle разработчиком android почти с нуля, имеется ввиду, что хотелось бы, чтобы вы поделились литературой или возможными путями развития.
Есть базовые знания по java, по книге Хорстмана до 9 главы
В android базовые знания kotlin, recyclerview, различные layout'ы, навигация по фрагментам боковое меню (что-то наподобие navigation drawer)
Начинаю изучать mvvm. И вот , хотелось бы узнать различные и эффективные пути становления разработчиком среднего уровня. Хотелось бы дойти до этого уровня за пол года, при , конечно, выделении времени по часов 6-8 почти каждый день.

Comment: Возможно, [этот вопрос и ответы к нему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692639/192249) будут полезны.

Comment: @Ivan, хоть я и не отношусь к вопросу, но спасибо за ссылку! Мне пригодится )

Comment: За полгода до джуна дорастите, хотя бы.

Comment: мидл это уже не столько книжки читать, сколько практика, нестандартные решения не из книжек, креативность и способность самостоятельно решать проблемы, когда что то идет не по книжке (а не по книжке идет всегда), для этого нужно участие во многих реальных проектах и определенный склад ума, полгода слишком малый срок. То есть вам нужно уже не знать RecyclerView, как виджет, а уметь его разобрать и понять, почему он не делает то, что от него требуется или написать собственный LayoutManager для вывода айтемов по спирали или крестиком, писать собственный код под задачу, а не использовать готовый

Comment: только участие в реальных проектах. и не за полгода а за полтора-два

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно бежать впереди паровоза. Солдат сразу генералом стать не может.

Для начала вам нужно устроиться на какую-нибудь работу на позицию junior android разработчика. В идеале в компанию, где есть другие разработчики, чтобы они вас курировали.
Скорее всего первое время вам придется работать 24/7 и работать "за еду".

Мало компаний кого интересуют джуниоры. Поэтому придется напрячься и походить на десяток собеседований, чтобы получить опыт прохождения и попыться куда-нибудь попасть.

После этого вы будете работать в компании и нарабатывать опыт. Напишите пару приложений. Поработаете с различными архитектурами, столкнетесь с огромным количеством задач, научитесь на ошибках правильно оценивать задачи и свои силы.
Имея весь этот бэкграунд, вы сами поймете,что вы уже выросли с уровня junior на уровень middle.