# Как получить значение из одного окна в другое окно, android-приложение?

Tags: android

Андроид-приложение.
Допустим есть MainActivity в которой есть String str, и есть NextActivity. Как получить в NextActivity значение str?

Comment: Это написано в любой методичке по написанию андроид-приложений на третьей странице.

Comment: @Эникейщик можно ссылку на хороший учебник?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты когда запускаешь второе активистки из первого, ты делаешь это с помощью Intent, в котором можно передать текстовое значение через intent.putExtra:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwoActivity.class); 
    intent.putExtra("fname", etFName.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
```

А потом во втором активити вытащить эти данные через intent.getExtra:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);
         
        Intent intent = getIntent();
         
        String fName = intent.getStringExtra("fname");
```