# Как сделать приложение, которое будет выводить toast на третьем холодном старте?

Tags: android, android-toast

Всем привет!
Я не могу понять, как мне сделать, приложение, которое будет на Третьем холодном старте выводить какой-то toast.
Может кто-нибудь в курсе как - это сделать, или вы знаете проект в котором, это реализовано?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-android)

Comment: По идее холодным стартом можно считать вызов onCreate в классе Application. В нём вы можете в префы записывать кол-во запусков этого метода и показывать Toast