# Как создать библиотеку книг на Java?

Tags: java

Я начинающий программист на Java
мне захотелось сделать библиотеку книг (типа приложения), но не знаю с чего лучше начать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/692639/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-android)

Comment: и просто книг по java https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416634/191482

Answer (score 2):

Существует несколько способов создать приложение на Java:

Создать простую версию для компьютеров с графическим интерфейсом на старенькой библиотеке Swing. Внешний вид будет следующий:

[image: источник https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)]

Преимущество данного подхода заключается в том, что вы сможете попрактиковаться в применении ООП и паттернов проектирования.

---

Создать приложение с новым графическим дизайном с применением JavaFX (https://openjfx.io/). Для его создания потребуется знание спецификации платформы. Выглядеть приложение будет несколько свежее:

[image: источник https://code.makery.ch/ru/library/javafx-tutorial/part1/]

Кроме того, платформа поддерживает CSS для кастомизации элементов. На ютубе много видео уроков о том, как пользоваться платформой.

---

Пойти еще дальше и написать backend приложение на Java, а в качестве графического приложения будет выступать любое клиентское приложение, поддерживающее протокол http для коммуникации.

---

Реализовать приложение на Vaadin. К сожаления мне пока не приходилось с ним работать, поэтому информацию о нем можете найти в браузере.

О сравнении JavaFX и Swing написана хорошая [статья](https://www.educba.com/java-swing-vs-java-fx/).